# 502 Invalid Response when calling Google Api from Azure Website

Tags: azure, google-api

When I call Google APIs from an Azure website, I get **502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server**. The exact code works from both my local machine as well as an Azure VM.

The code is simply to get a display name from a Google user id

```
private string GetUserDetails(string userId)
{
    var serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    var certFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/googlekey.p12");
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
       new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
       {
           Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
       }.FromCertificate(certificate));

    var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Bayfront"
    });

    var request = service.People.Get(userId);
    var person = request.Execute();
    return person.DisplayName;
}
```

This was being called in a WebApi project, but I have extracted it to a single page asp.net web form at http://testgplus.azurewebsites.net/

I have also tried a simple REST client with an ApiKey instead of using the above. Again this works on the VM, but not on the web site, where I get a 403 Forbidden. I have added the IP addresses of the website & the VM to the Google Developers Console.

```
private string GetUserDetails2(string userId)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/" + userId);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddParameter("key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        dynamic result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        return result["name"]["givenName"];
    }
    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

It looks like I cannot call an outside web service for an Azure website. I have seen some similar issues, e.g. [502 requesting payment service inside azure 'website'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057646/502-requesting-payment-service-inside-azure-website), but none of the suggestions has worked. Has anyone got any ideas on what the cause or fix might be?

Answer (score 4):

I saw your question before, but didn't noticed the solution... I have it now also.. When generating the certificate add:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(p12Path, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
//(notice the X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |)
```

Answer (score 1):

. Hi Colin Mierowsky

Where are you create certificate, in Application_Start,  or WebApiConfig Register method  ?

where use this code ?

```
makecert -r -n "CN=abdullahsargin.com, E=sargin48@gmail.com" -sky exchange -b 11/01/2015 -pe -sv myhost.pvk myhost.cer

pvk2pfx -pvk myhost.pvk -spc myhost.cer -pfx myhost.pfx -po Test.123
```

In global.asax  application_start

```
         try
        {
            var certFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/myhost.pfx");
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "Test.123",
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            _tools.LogError(exc);
        }
```

.
this method running success on local but in azure get 502 on this code, i test this method row and row

```
  var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

complete of this method

```
    [HttpGet, AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ForgotPassword([FromUri] ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {               
            var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { model = user });

            var url = "http://abdullahsargin.com#/account/resetPassword/" + user.Id + "/" + code;

            await _userManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password",
            "Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href=\"" + url + "\">link</a>");

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MyTools.LogError(exc.GetBaseException());
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, exc.GetBaseException());
        }
    }
```

i find at this page my solution

[ASP.NET Identity: use GeneratePasswordResetToken on Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740139/asp-net-identity-use-generatepasswordresettoken-on-azure-website)

for my solution

```
public UserManager() : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MyDbContext()))
{
    // other setup
    this.UserTokenProvider = new TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>();
}
```