# 502 error when generating X509Certificate2 from p12 certificate in Azure Websites for Google API

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, google-api

I'm using [This `GoogleJsonWebToken`](https://zavitax.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/logging-in-with-google-service-account-in-c-jwt/) class to generate an access token to be used with json calls to the Google Calendar API. It works perfectly fine in IIS Express on my dev machine when I use the following (using my actual service account email):

```
string p12Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/certificate.p12");
var auth = GoogleJsonWebToken.GetAccessToken("uniquestring@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
                                             p12Path,
                                             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
string Token = auth["access_token"];
```

To test this I'm just calling `@Token` in my cshtml razor view. When I publish this to my Azure website it doesn't work. If i leave the `GoogleJsonWebToken` class unmodified I get a very unhelpful `502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.` with no other information.

After some Google searches I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858398/502-invalid-response-when-calling-google-api-from-azure-website) which is a similar problem. So I tried their solution I get `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.` when that is run from my Azure Website. When it is run from my dev machine I get `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` which I think is because with that solution the `CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName` is `null` whereas the original unmodified class when run on my dev machine gives me something like `{C0E26DC5-5D2C-4C77-8E40-79560F519588}` which is randomly generated each time and this value is used in the process of signing the signature.

I then found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874317/x509certificate2-failing-in-azure-webjobs-calling-google-api) but that solution yielded the same results as the last solution.

I have also tried most of the different combinations of `X509KeyStorageFlags` to no avail.

How can I either generate the `CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName` myself or otherwise successfully generate the `X509Certificate2`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the solution on [this MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ea48fd0-8d6b-43ed-b272-1a0249ae490f/systemsecuritycryptographycryptographicexception-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified?forum=clr). Basically I needed to set `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` as I read in the first SO post I mentioned and then I needed `Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore` in my CspParamaters.

I have posted my [full solution on GitHub](https://github.com/mhcodner/GoogleJsonWebToken/blob/master/GoogleJsonWebToken.cs)

Comment: Yep, this did it for me

Comment: Exactly the same problem. Replacing X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet  with X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know if there are security implications to this? I believe for Azure web apps, there are multiple tenants per physical (or virtual?) machine.

Comment: @BenjiFB If you are worried about security implications you wouldn't be using an Azure web app. It is true that there are multiple tenants per physical host but they are not within the same VM.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you should add the p12 file to resources:

Right click on project - properties - resources - add resource 
and after that use this line of code for the certificate

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2((byte[])Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(ResourceName), "!password!", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```